# Не понимаю как работает код

Tags: python, строки, while

Условие задачи:

> Текстовый файл состоит не более чем из 106 символов X, Y и Z.
> Определите максимальную длину цепочки вида XYZXYZXYZ... (составленной
> из фрагментов XYZ, последний фрагмент может быть неполным).

Пробовал написать код сам, но он не справлялся даже с короткой строкой, поэтому начал искать решения других людей. Нашёл код который верно обрабатывал файл, но если я создавал строку сам, то код работало не корректно. Наткнулся на это решение и оно справляется и с той строкой которую я придумал, и с той строкой, которая находится в файле. Но проблема в том, что я не понимаю как это работает.

1. Что делает in в цикле while?
2. Почему в условиях из значения длинны что-то вычитается?

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться

```
s = "XYZXZZYYZXYZXYZXYZX"
k = 'XYZ'
while k in s:
  k +=  'XYZ'
l = len (k)
if k in s: print (l-1)
elif k[:l -  2] in s: print (l -  2)
else: print (l -  3)
```

Comment: `in` определяет вхождение, метод прикольный. После выхода из `while` в `k` может быть лишний раз записан искомый элемент, поэтому дальше идут попытки это выяснить и скорректировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ниже идет описание работы алгоритма, я не считаю его оптимальным, он практически не демонстирует никаких навыков - это простой брутфорс.
На мой взгляд единичный посимвольный проход всей строки был бы куда эффективнее - O(n) и продемонстрировал больше навыков.

```
s = "XYZXZZYYZXYZXYZXYZX"
k = 'XYZ' # (инициализация)
'''
cтрока k приращивается каждый раз на XYZ
и проверяется находится ли такая подстрока в s
с помощью оператора in
'''
while k in s:
  print('i')
  k +=  'XYZ'

'''
так как в цикле авансом прбавляются
3 cимвола без проверки их наличия (инициализация)
то для того чтобы найти неполные строки 
используется вычитание из длины
'''
l = len (k) # получаем длину заведомо болшую

'''
это условие "сработает, если k in s: False – Интик"
потому что XYZ + XYZ не содержится в XYZ
'''
if k in s: print ('a', l-1) 
'''
тут мы отнимаем сразу 2 символа
k[:l - 2] эквивалентно k[:-2]
XYZXYZX.. и ищем в s
'''
elif k[:l -  2] in s: print ('b', l -  2)
'''
иначе неглядя отнимаем три символа
XYZXYZ...
'''
else: print ('c',l -  3)

'''
таким образом код работает не правильно
из-за не полноты проверки

s = "XY"
k = 'XYZ'

должно вернуть 2 но возвращает 1

s = "XYZXY"
k = 'XYZ'

должно вернуть 5 но возвращает 4


s = "XYZXYZXY"
k = 'XYZ'

должно вернуть 8 но возвращает 7
'''
```